# How to update an iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I got an App on AppStore, but since I launched it on the store, I have made some changes. How do I update my App to appstore?

Thanks

**Needless to say, i JUST wan't to rename my Application so that it shows a different name on the Home screen of the user**

Answer (score 2):

Go to itunesconnect.apple.com and login. Then you go on manage applications and choose your app to update. There you can prepare your app to the update with informations etc.

To Rename the app you have to look in the plist file. There is a row for the product name. This is the name that is displayed on the screen.

After this. Archive the App with the distribution provisoning file and submit mit through the organizer.

Answer (score 1):

An update is pretty much the same process as the initial release. Make your changes and test on your device. When you are happy with it, build the release version and use the "Add Version" button in itunesconnect to upload the new version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

In your plist you can change the "Bundle display name" key. If your bundle identifier remains the same this will just change the name of your app in springboard.

Answer (score 0):

App update process is smilier to new release app but you have to remember two major things.

- Change the version of your app in plist file
- Add a new version of your app in ituneconnect with the same version no you entered into the plist file.